# Can I submit form on timeout even if required fields are not filled

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit, required

I was wondering if it is possible to submit a form after a certain period of time (e.g. 2 minutes) even if not all the required fields are filled out, as I would like all the data entered by that fixed period of time to be submitted. Currently, although I'm using a timeout function that is javascript-based, it does not allow for the form to be submitted upon timeout as the required fields are not completed. I set all the fields to required as the autofocus function does not seem to work if it is not a required field (i.e. does not go into the next input field automatically upon pressing enter in the current field. Is there a way around this? Thanks so much for any help!

```js
window.setTimeout(() => this.submit(), 120000)
```

```html
<html>
 <main>
  <form>

     <br><label for="response1"><b>Animals</b></label><br>
     <input type="text" id="response1" name="response1" autocomplete="off" autofocus required></br>

     <br><input type="text" id="response2" name="response2" autocomplete="off" autofocus required></br>

     <br><input type="text" id="response3" name="response3" autocomplete="off" autofocus required></br>

     <br><input type="text" id="response4" name="response4" autocomplete="off" autofocus required></br>
     
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
 </main>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just put this logic in your function. You just remove `required` attribute from fields.

```
let form = document.querySelector('form');
let inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
let i;

for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].required = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple problems with your code:

1. you should not open and close br tags, you just put a `<br>` where you want the line break
2. the autofocus attribute should only be placed on one input, and that input will have the focus when the page loads.
3. depending on how you are calling your code, you might run in to problems with the `this` keyword, you might be better calling the form directly.

I changed those things in your code and succeeded with the following code (no need to remove the required attributes, but if they are not really needed just remove them):

```js
window.setTimeout(() => document.forms[0].submit(), 1000)
```

```html
<html>
<main>
<form>
    <br>
    <label for="response1">
        <b>Animals</b>
    </label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="response1" name="response1" autocomplete="off" autofocus required>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="response2" name="response2" autocomplete="off" required>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="response3" name="response3" autocomplete="off" required>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="response4" name="response4" autocomplete="off" required>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</main>

</html>
```

I changed the timeout to one second just to be able to see the effect.